# Camera and Microphone Permission for NativeScript Web View

Tags: android, angular, android-webview, nativescript

I am building an Android App using NativeScript Angular. I am implementing a video call feature in the app. The HTML5 client for the video call has to open in a Web View and I am trying to give camera and microphone permissions to it. Can someone guide me on how to do it?

Comment: You will have to implement custom WebChromeClient and override onPermissionRequest, ask for permissions natively using nativescript permissions plugin perhaps.